# AWS Lambda Stop EC2 but exclude two instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We are looking for AWS Lambda Script to Stop all EC2 instances in a particular region expect two instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add tags for the instances that you want to stop, for example, AutoStop tag and assign them with value True, and then run this code:

```py
import boto3
import logging

#setup simple logging for INFO
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#define the connection
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Use the filter() method of the instances collection to retrieve
    # all running EC2 instances.
    filters = [{
            'Name': 'tag:AutoOff',
            'Values': ['True']
        },
        {
            'Name': 'instance-state-name', 
            'Values': ['running']
        },
        {
            'Name': 'region', 
            'Values': ['us-east-1'] #replace it with your region
        }
    ]

    #filter the instances
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)

    #locate all running instances
    RunningInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]

    #print the instances for logging purposes
    #print RunningInstances 

    #make sure there are actually instances to shut down. 
    if len(RunningInstances) > 0:
        #perform the shutdown
        shuttingDown = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=RunningInstances).stop()
        print shuttingDown
    else:
        print "Nothing to see here"
```